# Generating social media links

Tags: php

I'm building an option panel for a Wordpress theme. I'm just learning PHP and I wonder if there is any better (shorter) way to generate the social media links. Here's what I came up with and even tho it works, I think there are cleaner way to write it

```
<ul>
<?php if ( of_get_option('mm_sm_vimeo') ) { ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('mm_sm_vimeo'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/socials/ico_vimeo.png" alt="Vimeo"/></a><span>Vimeo</span>
</li>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( of_get_option('mm_sm_gplus') ) { ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('mm_sm_gplus'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/socials/ico_gplus.png" alt="Google Plus"/></a><span>Google Plus</span>
</li>
```

Etc... etc... over 20 times.

Maybe a loop or something? The problem is that I have a different Option name for each and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Your code is scrambled, plesse edit it.

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to write this, and yes, it would involve a loop. Is this the answer you're looking for?

Comment: wordpress and clean doesn't come together...

Comment: ...but wordpress doesn't force you to switch back and forth between html and php rather than embedding html in php in html.

Comment: You should combine these options into one option. you can put an array in `add_option` and retrieve that array in `get_option`

Answer (score 2):

You could take the common bits out into a function:

```
<?php
function my_thing($name, $title) {
   if ( of_get_option("mm_sm_$name") ) {
      ?>
      <li>
      <a href="<?php echo of_get_option("mm_sm_$name"); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/socials/ico_<?php echo $name ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $title ?>"/></a><span><?php echo $title ?></span>
      </li>
      <?
   }
}

my_thing('vimeo', 'Vimeo');
my_thing('gplus', 'Google Plus');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the data array and iterate through its elements:

```
<ul>
<?php
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Vimeo', 'option' => 'mm_sm_vimeo', 'icon' => 'ico_vimeo.png'),
    array('name' => 'Google Plus', 'option' => 'mm_sm_gplus', 'icon' => 'ico_gplus.png'),
    // other elements go here in the same format
);

foreach($data as $item) {
    if (of_get_option($item['option'])) {
        ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?= of_get_option($item['option'])?>"><img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/socials/<?= $item['icon'] ?>" alt="<?= $item['name'] ?>"/></a><span><?= $item['name'] ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Or using templates and without explicit iterating:

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Vimeo', 'option' => 'mm_sm_vimeo', 'icon' => 'ico_vimeo.png'),
    array('name' => 'Google Plus', 'option' => 'mm_sm_gplus', 'icon' => 'ico_gplus.png'),
);

function printItem($item)
{
    if (!of_get_option($item['option'])) {
        return;
    }
    $template = '<li>
    <a href="%s"><img src="%s/images/socials/%s" alt="%s"/></a><span>%s</span>
    </li>';
    echo sprintf($template, of_get_option($item['option']), get_template_directory_uri(), $item['icon'], $item['name'], $item['name']);
}

function printData($data) {
    echo '<ul>';
    array_walk($data, 'printItem');
    echo '</ul>';
}

printData($data);
```

Anyway, main idea is not to duplicate some code 20 times, use data source (like array in this example) and iterate through its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to a number of the answers already here. However, none are using heredoc and I think in this case it is cleaner because of all the variables you are trying to pass to HTML, especially on that one line.

```
$template_directory = get_template_directory_uri();
$options = array(
    'vimeo' => 'Vimeo',
    'gplus' => 'Google Plus',
    //etc...
);
?>

<ul>

<?php
foreach( $options AS $option => $name ) {
    $link = of_get_option( "mm_sm_$option" );

    echo <<<HTML
        <li>
            <a href="$link">
                <img src="$template_directory/images/socials/ico_$option.png" alt="$name"/>
            </a>
            <span>$name</span>
        </li>

HTML;
}
?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just refactor it.

```
<?php     $data = array('vimeo' => 'vimeo', 'gplus' => 'Google Plus');  ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$val){
if ( of_get_option('mm_sm_'.$key) ) { ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('mm_sm_'.$key); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/socials/ico_<?php echo $key ?>" alt="<?php echo $val; ?>"/></a><span><?php echo $val; ?></span>
</li>
<?php } 
}?>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Here the key point is the `$data` array. populate it and the loop will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiary with wordpress so i can only give you some hints
regarding the style of mixing php and html.
Use the templating style of php. It will look a lot cleaner:

```
<ul>
    <?php if ( of_get_option('mm_sm_vimeo') ): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo of_get_option('mm_sm_vimeo'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/socials/ico_vimeo.png" alt="Vimeo"/></a><span>Vimeo</span>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( of_get_option('mm_sm_gplus') ): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo of_get_option('mm_sm_gplus'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/socials/ico_gplus.png" alt="Google Plus"/></a><span>Google Plus</span>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

as for loops:

```
<?php foreach($container as $var): ?>
    <html />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i like this way cleaner